# how to prevent Sharepoint site from stopping when debugging?

Tags: debugging, sharepoint

Every time I atach to the w3wP.exe process for debugging purposes, the entire site stops and other users or developers cant interact/debug with the sharepoint site. is there a solution/workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no workaround for this. It is standard behavior of debugging process. That is why generally each developer has own dev environment.